# How to delete dynamic elements stored in a std::forward_list

Tags: c++

I'm using a std::forward_list in C++ to store dynamically allocated elements.  I'm wondering what the correct way to 'delete' the elements in list, or free the memory.

```
std::forward_list<int> integerList;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int* intPtr = new int(i); 
    integerList.push_front(*intPtr);
}
```

After this code executes, I think what should happen is the forward_list holds a dynamically allocated int.  Now, how would I go about properly calling delete on it?  I noticed the forward_list container has a clear() function, but does that call delete on all of the elements in each node?

Comment: `I'm using a std::forward_list in C++ to store dynamically allocated elements.` Hmm no, youre not doing that at all. Youre storing *copies* of these elements and leaking the original.

Comment: @Borgleader good catch.  I missed that.

Comment: Thanks guys, this makes sense.  So what is the correct way to delete the original and make sure I don't leak it?  Should I add delete intPtr; in the last line of the for loop?

Comment: Adding delete would fix the leak, but you didnt need to new the int in the first place. `integerList.push_front(i);` would work [just as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65f4177a35d52038)

Comment: Yes I understand, my issue's a little more complicated where I do need 'new', so I just wondered how this should be dealt with.  Thank you!

Comment: Well you need to change the type of the list for one: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c68c42b9c8b8187b)

Comment: @AWoodman if you use raw pointers, you will have to iterate through the list and call delete on each pointer.  But raw pointers are less than ideal. Consider using a smart pointer which will call delete for you when the object being pointed to is no longer in use.

Comment: Thanks Borgleader, so you're saying I should have a list of int*, rather than int.  I considered this but wasn't sure.  Appreciate the help everyone!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need to use `new`? Do you have enough experience in the language to be able to make that determination? The fact that you don't even know how and when you should use `delete` suggests that you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think what should happen is the forward_list holds a dynamically allocated int

No, it doesn't hold dynamically allocated `int`. The type of element is `int`, when `integerList.push_front(*intPtr);`, the value will be copied.

On the other hand, you get a memory leak in the for loop, you need to `delete` what you `new`ed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int* intPtr = new int(i); 
    integerList.push_front(*intPtr);
    delete intPtr;
}
```

If you want to save dynamically allocated elements, you should declare the type of element as pointer, and delete the elements by yourself at last.

```
std::forward_list<int*> integerList;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int* intPtr = new int(i); 
    integerList.push_front(intPtr);
}
...
for (auto e : integerList) {
    delete e;
}
```

And you could use smart pointers to avoid this kind of memory management, such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will have to iterate through the list and call delete each pointer element.

Comment: Wrong, look at the type of the list (and how each element is added)

Comment: Correct, I missed that.  Let's assume that is corrected :).